# Ajax form request

Tags: php, forms, jquery

I have a issue with my ajax form submission.I am dynamically submitting a form and using php at the server side to process it.This is the ajax success function.

```
   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "register.php",
                        data: "uname="+uname+"&eid="+eid+"&pwd="+pass+"&cpwd="+cpass+"&country="+coun+"&contact="+contact,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data!="error")
                            {   
                               //alert(data);
                                $("#user_status", window.parent.document).html("Welcome "+data+"&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='forum/logout.php'>Logout</a>");
                                if(window.parent.document.getElementById('post_user_name'))
                                    $("#post_user_name", window.parent.document).html(msg);
                                parent.$.fancybox.close();
                            }
                            if(data=="error")
                            {   
                                //alert(data);
                                $("#status").html("<span><center><font class='formright err_msg' style='width:176px;'>The user is already register with us.</font><center></span>");
                                return false;
                            }
```

Now if the user is valid he is logged in and f not there has to be an error like "Already exists".The valid part works fine but for invalid I return an **error** from the php file but still my error message doesn't show up and just error is printed on the screen.I am using fancybox for my forms(jquery fancybox)
PHP code is

```
        if($_POST['pwd']==$_POST['cpwd'])
            {
                $username   = $_POST['uname'];
                $email      = $_POST['eid'];
                $password   = md5($_POST['pwd']);
                $cpassword  = $_POST['cpwd'];
                $contact_no = $_POST['contact'];
                $country    = $_POST['country'];

                $cnt      =     $checkUser['cnt'];

                if($cnt!=0) 
                {
                    echo "error";
                    //exit;
                    /*$_SESSION['error_msg']    =   'Email Address already exists';
                    redirect_to_link("index.html");*/

                } 
                else
                {
                    //echo "entered here";
                    $userArray = array();
                    //$user = return_post_value($_POST['uname']);
                    $userArray['uname'] = return_post_value($_POST['uname']);
                    $userArray['email'] = return_post_value($_POST['eid']);
                    $userArray['password'] = md5(return_post_value($_POST['pwd']));
                    $userArray['contact_no'] = return_post_value($_POST['contact']);
                    $userArray['country'] = return_post_value($_POST['country']);

                    //print_r($userArray);
                    //exit;
                    $userObj->addUserValue($userArray);
                    $_SESSION['username']=  $userArray['uname'];            
                    echo $userArray['uname'];
                                  //    return $user;
                }
```

The **echo $userArray['uname'];** part works but **echo "error"** doesn't.Checked in Firebug response header,i can see the error word returned.
Can anyone throw some light on it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you do an alert on data on Javascript after you get the response. And why are you doing a return false; on the if(data=='error') condition?

Comment: yes tried that but it does not reach there it still goes into the (data!="error") loop!!I am not getting why when its not equal!! :P I am trying to do something similar here http://www.proptiger.com/ in the header **Register** link (form). Thanks

Comment: Can please print the value of data in success function and provide the output here ?

Comment: @subirkumarsao The return false is bcoz after the error i don't want the form to submit and the **user already exits** message to be displayed.Its a sign up form not a login one.

Comment: We need to see whats in that data. As you are sayings you can see "error" in the firebug response then it can be white spaces before and after the "error". Do a alert before the if(data!="error") and post the output. Something like alert('A'+data+'A');. Makes easy to understand if there are white spaces

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel The value of data in success turns to be what I echo in the  `if($cnt!=0) 
                {
                    echo "error";
                    //exit;
 

                } ` loop(if user exists).So if the condition is valid i.e if its a new user,everything works fine and username is displayed as on the link I provided in above comment,but if the user already exists,it just prints/alerts "error" and goes in the `if(data!=error){}` loop!! Thanks

Comment: @Sachin Ya that i can make out from the question posted but I just wanted to know whether the data that you are receiving is faling the conditional statement.

Comment: @subirkumarsao Yes it is white spaces it comes out as **A error (space)A**.How to eliminate these?????? :P

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel Got your point!! Thanks for the inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to compare if($.trim(data)!="error")

And don't recheck for if($.trim(data)=="error")

use

```
if($.trim(data)!="error")
{
 //
}
else{
//
}
```

Comment: Worked!!!!!Gem **subirkumar**.Thanks to you too **Codemaster Gabriel** .Also can't I eliminate the white spaces on server side.I tried adding this `stripslashes` to remove any whitespaces,but did not work!! And also the part from where I reffered this example doesn't have it!! Then what's the reason?can you please comment on this and elaborate a bit. Thanks

Comment: stripslashes doesnot remove the whitespaces on the server side. trim(), ltrim(), rtrim() are the functions that are available to remove the whitespaces even on the server side.

Comment: I guess you have a empty space after the php close tag ?><space> Please check.

Comment: @subirkumarsao No there was no space after close tag as you mentioned(cross checked it). Codemaster Gabriel ohhh...I have been away from php for some while and I think i need to revisit the functions section on php.net!! :P Thanks both for the inputs!